# How can I format the output of a proxy function to be on separate lines?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have created a proxy function to Get-ADUser which adds some AD attributes to the output. I'm trying to format them so that they're more easily read.  I'd like both additional attributes to be formatted in a vertical list, something like this:

```
Name              : Joe Bloggs
DistinguishedName : CN=Joe Blogs,OU=User,etc.
ProxyAddresses    : j.bloggs@blah.com
                    user.admin@blah.com
                    mr.big@blah.com
Member of         : ABCGroup1
                    ABCGroup2
                    ABCGroup3
```

At the moment, proxyAddresses is formatted as `'j.bloggs@blah.com user.admin@blah.com mr.big@blah.commember'` and memberOf of is formatted as `'{ABCGroup1, ABCGroup2, ABCGroup3}'`

To recreate.  Create a module:

```
New-ModuleManifest 'C:\Users\user-id\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TestModule1\TestModule1.psd1' -FormatsToProcess 'TestModule1.format.ps1xml' -ScriptsToProcess 'Get-ADUserEx.ps1'
```

Create a proxy function to Get-ADUser using at `C:\Users\user-id\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TestModule1\Get-ADUserEx.ps1` (code at end) and a format file at: `C:\Users\user-id\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TestModule1\TestModule1.format.ps1xml` containing:

I've added that proxy function to a new module, which also has a TestModule1.format.ps1xml file containing a view defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <SelectionSets>
  </SelectionSets>
  <Controls>
  </Controls>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>ADABCUserList</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>ABC.ADUserEx</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <ListControl>
        <ListEntries>
          <ListEntry>
            <ListItems>
              <ListItem>
                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem>
                <PropertyName>DistinguishedName</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem>
                <PropertyName>ProxyAddresses</PropertyName>
                <FormatString>{0}</FormatString>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem>
                <Label>ABC Group(s):</Label>
                <ScriptBlock>
                    foreach ($item in $_.MemberOf) {
                        if ($item -match 'ABC') {
                            $commaIndex = $item.IndexOf(',OU=')
                            $cn = $item.Substring(3, $commaIndex - 3)
                            "{0}" -f $cn
                        }
                    }
                </ScriptBlock>
              </ListItem>
            </ListItems>
          </ListEntry>
        </ListEntries>
      </ListControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function Get-ADUserEx {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Filter')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter', Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${Filter},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LdapFilter', Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${LDAPFilter},

        [Alias('Property')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        ${Properties},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LdapFilter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [int]
        ${ResultPageSize},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LdapFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [System.Nullable[int]]
        ${ResultSetSize},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LdapFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]
        ${SearchBase},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LdapFilter')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADSearchScope]
        ${SearchScope},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Identity', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]
        ${Identity},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Identity')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${Partition},

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${Server},

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [pscredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
        ${Credential},

        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAuthType]
        ${AuthType})

    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }

            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-ADUser', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)

            $props = @(
                'ProxyAddresses',
                'MemberOf'
            )

            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Properties')) {
                foreach ($prop in $PSBoundParameters['Properties']) {
                    if (-not $props.Contains($prop)) {
                        $props += $prop
                    }
                }
            }

            $PSBoundParameters['Properties'] = $props

            $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters | 
                    ForEach-Object { 
                        $_.PSTypeNames.Insert(0,'ABC.ADUserEx'); 
                        $_ 
                    }
            }

            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
    <#

    .ForwardHelpTargetName Get-ADUser
    .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

    #>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default behavior of how Out-Host is formatting your object members. Whenever you see { }, it's because that member is a collection (you might have already known that, just pointing out for thoroughness).

That said... if you're wanting it to print "pretty" in the console, you're going to have to concatenate one big string instead of using a collection. The key to this is to use "`n" in your strings to create a new line return.

I tested this briefly with your XML and it worked, but I imagine you'll need to do some tweaking to make sure it splits your string correctly and formats the way you want it.

For the proxy addresses, I was able to get away with this. Worst case scenario is you'd have to use $_.split(" ") if the addresses aren't returning as an array.

```
    <ListItem>
        <Label>ProxyAddressesPretty</Label>
        <ScriptBlock>
            $_.ProxyAddresses | %{
                $return += $_ + "`n"
            }
            return $return
        </ScriptBlock>
    </ListItem>
```

I used a similar approach to MemberOf groups

```
    <ScriptBlock>
        $groups = ""
        foreach ($item in $_.MemberOf) {
            $commaIndex = $item.IndexOf(',OU=')
            $cn = $item.Substring(3, $commaIndex - 3)
            $groups += "$cn`n"
        }
        return $groups
    </ScriptBlock>
```

Hope that helps...